# Wpf control existing Shapes with vb code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Good day, been trying to control some custom shapes that I have added with vb code without luck yet.

So far this is the code that I´m using it doesnt show any errors but wont do anything on the desired shape.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Myshape As Shape
    Myshape = Path_2
    Myshape.opacity= 50
end sub
```

does anyone know how to control existing shapes or other elements? thanks a lot, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if your problem is linked to the opacity? But if this is the case, the opacity is a percentage value (so between 0 and 1) and you are trying to apply the value 50.